# Create a new datastore on Dropbox API - error message : com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxRuntimeException$Cache:

Tags: java, android, dropbox-api

I'm developing an app to do shopping lists. The content of those lists are stored inside of tables of a  database. My goal is to share some of these tables between several devices. In this way, I have chosen to send these tables on Dropbox datastore.

In a first step, I try to create a new Dropbox datastore by following this tutorial [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/android). But after running my app on my real device (Android 4.2.2), I'm stuck on an error message. Below I show the error message, the code activity, and the manifest.

Error message :

```
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.example.dvp_list7/com.example.dvp_list7.ListingArticlesDropb}: com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxRuntimeException$Cache: jlong dropboxsync::Java_com_dropbox_sync_android_NativeDatastoreManager_nativeOpenOrCreateDs(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jstring) - Cache error: void dropbox::KvCacheBase::kv_set_impl(const checked_lock&, const string&, const string&) (jni/../../../common/base/sqlite_util.cpp:155): disk I/O error
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3337)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3380)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:155)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5096)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978): Caused by: com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxRuntimeException$Cache: jlong dropboxsync::Java_com_dropbox_sync_android_NativeDatastoreManager_nativeOpenOrCreateDs(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jstring) - Cache error: void dropbox::KvCacheBase::kv_set_impl(const checked_lock&, const string&, const string&) (jni/../../../common/base/sqlite_util.cpp:155): disk I/O error
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxError.exceptionFrom(DbxError.java:235)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeLib.exceptionFrom(NativeLib.java:254)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeLib.throwFrom(NativeLib.java:242)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeDatastoreManager.nativeOpenOrCreateDs(Native Method)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeDatastoreManager.nativeOpenOrCreateDs(Native Method)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.NativeDatastoreManager.openOrCreateDatastore(NativeDatastoreManager.java:140)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxDatastoreManager.openOrCreateDatastore(DbxDatastoreManager.java:342)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at com.example.dvp_list7.ListingArticlesDropb.onActivityResult(ListingArticlesDropb.java:100)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5342)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3333)
10-22 00:29:03.473: E/AndroidRuntime(19978):    ... 11 more
```

By running my app with the debug mode of Eclipse, I know that the line of the issue is:

```
    try {
   //  This line makes my app to stop.
        DbxDatastore datastore = mDatastoreManager.openOrCreateDatastore("articles");
    } catch (DbxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Activity code (ListingArticlesDropb .java) :

```
public class ListingArticlesDropb extends Activity implements PersonneAdapterListener{


    static final int REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX = 0;  // This value is up to you

    private Button mLinkButton;
    private Button mUnlinkButton;

    private DbxAccountManager mAccountManager;
    private DbxDatastoreManager mDatastoreManager;
    private DbxAccount account ;

    final private String APP_KEY = **** APP_KEY **** ;
    final private String APP_SECRET = **** APP_SECRET **** ;
    DbxDatastore datastore;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_articles);


        /**
         * Get objects from the precedent activity
         */
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        final String extras = bundle.getString("Title");

        /**
         * Connection to the datastore Dropbox
         */
        // Set up the account manager
        mAccountManager = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);   
        mAccountManager.startLink((Activity)ListingArticlesDropb.this, REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX);


        // Set up the datastore manager
        if (mAccountManager.hasLinkedAccount()) {
            try {
                // Use Dropbox datastores
                mDatastoreManager = DbxDatastoreManager.forAccount(mAccountManager.getLinkedAccount());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Connection Dropbox", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (DbxException.Unauthorized e) {
                System.out.println("Account was unlinked remotely");
            }
        }
        if (mDatastoreManager == null) {
            // Account isn't linked yet, use local datastores
            mDatastoreManager = DbxDatastoreManager.localManager(mAccountManager);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Connection Locale", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                account = mAccountManager.getLinkedAccount();
                Toast.makeText(this, "onActivityResult", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                try {
                    // Migrate any local datastores to the linked account
                    mDatastoreManager.migrateToAccount(account);
                    // Now use Dropbox datastores
                    mDatastoreManager = DbxDatastoreManager.forAccount(account);

                } catch (DbxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // Link failed or was cancelled by the user
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }


        // ---------- The problem comes here ------------- //
        try {
       //  This line makes my app to stop.
            DbxDatastore datastore = mDatastoreManager.openOrCreateDatastore("articles");
        } catch (DbxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


}
```

Manifest code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dvp_list7"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.dvp_list7.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <!-- <activity android:name="com.example.dvp_list5.ListingArticles"
            android:label="@string/app_name" > -->

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.dvp_list7.ListingArticles"/>

        <activity android:name="com.example.dvp_list7.DropboxHelper"/>
        <activity android:name="com.example.dvp_list7.ListingArticlesDropb"/>


        <activity android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAuthActivity" />
        <activity
          android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleTask" >
          <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="db-qeojd5e8htkkswc" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxSyncService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="Dropbox Sync" />   
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you if you can solve my issue!

Comment: It appears to be a disk I/O error... is there something wrong with the disk in your device? (Trying other disk access would be nice.) Are you perhaps out of space? (I'm not sure what error you'd receive in that case.)

Comment: Thank you to help me! No I don't think it is a problem of space. I have just checked and there are 800Mo (over 2Go) of internal free memory in my device. Is it possible there is a port conflict between this app and another one? I throw hypothesis without being sure if it is relevant...

Comment: Do other disk writes succeed? (Maybe you can try to write a file and then read.)

Comment: When you mean a "disk writes succeed", do you wonder if I can install other app on my device? If it is, the answer is yes. 
I have tried to change my query toward Dropbox, by removing  `DbxDatastore datastore = mDatastoreManager.openOrCreateDatastore("articles");` and replace by `datastore = mDatastoreManager.openDefaultDatastore();` => the error message hasn't change!!

Comment: I meant whether your app can write to the disk at all. (So try an `openFileOutput` call?) The error is happening somewhere in sqlite, but try opening a file and just writing a byte. If that fails too, we can ignore the Sync SDK. It's easier to debug if you can take irrelevant variables away.

Comment: Actually this app can also write data into a database from my device. But I have not displayed the class doing that.

Comment: The problem seems linked with my app. 
Indeed, I have created a basic project with only 2 buttons : "Link to Dropbox" and "Unlink". In this project I have copy-past the code of the [dropbox tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/android), and inside of the method "onActivityResult" I have added the line `DbxDatastore datastore = mDatastoreManager.openOrCreateDatastore("articles)`. Result: No problem here, the new table is well created inside of the Dropbox datastore.